# FB login in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios10

I have FBSDK and all the required framework in my project.
But when logging in its printing on console without giving any result .

**Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=304 "(null)"**

even i have switched on the keychain access, info.plist is updated as per instructions given on developer.facebook.com
App gives result for the first time but for the second time it shows:

**Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=304 "(null)"**
or
**Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308 "(null)"**

when app is uninstalled then it again gives result for only one time.

Comment: After `login` for first time have you `logout`from you app?

Comment: Try reseting your simulator.

Comment: Thanks It worked for me